# How can I link a project with boost which relies on another library that uses boost

Tags: c++, linux, boost, g++

I'm trying to link my project against boost and another library that uses boost but haven't had success after hours spent tweaking my `Makefile`.

`Myproject` and `dep1.a` need `boost` to compile but I can't get to link with them.

The error I get is:

```
Parser.o): In function `boost::re_detail_107200::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::perl_matcher(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>)':

/deps/boost_1_72_0/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher.hpp:391: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107200::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
```

I need `libboost_regex`, `libboost_system`, and `libboost_date_time`.

Here is the `Makefile` code:

```
CC := g++

BASE_DIR := ../../../code/MyProject/

CC_FLAGS := -g -std=c++0x -I$(BASE_DIR)../dep1/include -I$(BASE_DIR)include
LD_FLAGS := -lrt -lpthread -L../../../../../deps/boost_1_72_0/stage/libboost_regex.a -L../../../../../deps/boost_1_72_0/stage/libboost_system.a -L../../../../../deps/boost_1_72_0/stage/libboost_date_time.a

CPP_FILES := $(wildcard $(BASE_DIR)src/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)))

STATIC_DEP := ../dep1/lib/dep1.a


bin/MyProject: $(OBJ_FILES) $(STATIC_DEP)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(STATIC_DEP) $(LD_FLAGS)

obj/%.o: $(BASE_DIR)src/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

../dep1/lib/dep1.a:
    $(MAKE) -C ../dep1
clean:
    rm -rf ./obj
    rm -rf ./bin
'''
```

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: Sorry i forgot about the error. i edited the post and included the error

Comment: I'm guessing that whatever `Parser.o` is, it isn't compiled with the libstdc++ c++11 abi but your boost libraries are https://stackoverflow.com/a/32500124/5494370

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing the -l for library vs the -L for load path ? Also, check to see if the names and paths for the lib files are exactly right.